# Why on Physics meta you neither receive nor lose reputations but on meta stack exchange you do?

Tags: discussion

Why on Physics meta you neither receive nor lose reputations but on meta stack exchange you do?

On Physics meta:

When someone either upvotes or downvotes one of your questions or answers then your number of reputations is unaffected.

But on meta stack exchange:

When someone upvotes one of your questions or answers then you receive 5 reputations, but when he/she downvotes then you lose 2 reputations.

But why it works like that? Why Physics meta is different than meta stack exchange in this manner?

Comment: Have you seen https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta?

Comment: @Shog9 Truly a very important link, but I feel that's not what the OP asked. He was asking why there's reputation changes for upvotes and downvotes on Mother Meta, but not on Child Metas such as Physics Meta.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal is right. That's what I am really asking.

Comment: @PrittBalagopal uh, you do realize that it says in the link shog provided that rep is not earned or lost on this specific (i.e., child) Meta?

Comment: @KyleKanos I know that there's no rep change on child meta's, the OP is asking **why** it's that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly because of historical reasons. Meta Stack Exchange is a relatively recent site: the role of mother meta was taken by Meta Stack Overflow until the two sites split in 2014 (if my memory serves). MSO was the first meta site and it started with its own rep system; later sites just got theirs from the main site. (I'm not sure why, but the answer is somewhere in the archives of MSE.)

Edit: found the relevant blog post, at https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/22/new-per-site-metas/.

Comment: 2014 sounds about right to me too.